# RSA SSL Key Encryption Change

Tags: mysql, ssl, rsa, encryption

On my website I have two function set up for encrypting and decrypting data that is stored in the mySQL database. The data is encrypted or decrypted using my SSL key.

```
function enkrypt($data) {
  $fp = fopen("/home/ssl/certs/cert.crt","r");
  $pub_key=fread($fp,8192);
  fclose($fp);
  openssl_get_publickey($pub_key);
  openssl_public_encrypt($data,$text,$pub_key);
  return base64_encode($text);
}
function dekrypt($data) {
  $data = base64_decode($data);
  $fp = fopen("/home/ssl/keys/key.key","r");
  $priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
  fclose($fp);
  $res = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
  openssl_private_decrypt($data,$text,$res);
  return $text;
}
```

My question about this is simple, and possibly stupid, but once my SSL certificate expires after a year, will my keys change and must I decrypt and re-encrypt all of my information with a new key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate can be renewed without changing the key pair. Just keep generating a new CSR each year from the same key pair. Or, if your CA permits, just keep resubmitting the *same* CSR.